# How hash_hmac handles hex input?

Tags: php, hmacsha1

I'm trying to do a hmac hash of some hex bytes in php. Not sure if I understand the hash or hex representation correctly as the 2 hashes do not match up, e.g.

```
<?php
echo bin2hex("\x32\x45\xff\xca".pack("N",1))."\n";
echo hash_hmac('sha1', '\x32\x45\xff\xca\x00\x00\x00\x01', 'secret')."\n";
echo hash_hmac('sha1', '\x32\x45\xff\xca'.pack("N",1), 'secret')."\n";
```

gives

```
3245ffca00000001
3710e984df2fe4c53e0a9760cf0480357c6e431c
6308db257308f3466430807eb622489c7fff84df
```

The bytes seem to be the same to me yet they give a different hash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess what, turns out what I needed was to use double quotes instead of single and both those hashes for `'\x32\x45\xff\xca\x00\x00\x00\x01'` are incorrect.

so

```
echo hash_hmac('sha1', "\x32\x45\xff\xca\x00\x00\x00\x01", 'secret')."\n";
echo hash_hmac('sha1', "\x32\x45\xff\xca".pack("N",1), 'secret')."\n";
```

gives the correct thing

```
cde1e3710b6265b77fd4ac84293e20d981e92a6a
cde1e3710b6265b77fd4ac84293e20d981e92a6a
```

Subtle but true, test it out [here](http://codepad.org/F23bOmTV)

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your input:

```
      echo hash_hmac('sha1', '\x32\x45\xff\xca\x00\x00\x00\x01', 'secret')."\n";
      echo hash_hmac('sha1', '\x32\x45\xff\xca'.pack("N",1), 'secret')."\n";
```

the strings which are to be `hash_hmac`d are different,

```
     echo '\x32\x45\xff\xca\x00\x00\x00\x01'; // output : \x32\x45\xff\xca\x00\x00\x00\x01
     echo '\x32\x45\xff\xca'.pack("N",1);     // output : \x32\x45\xff\xca
```

that's why your answer is coming up different.

Comment: Please make an effort to use proper spelling and grammar.  Using netspeak like "ur" and "ans" makes your posts *hard to read*.